# Простецкий вопрос для разбирающихся в Python

Tags: python-3.x

жители python сегмента stackoverflow. Возможно моя проблема покажется для вас лёгкой задачкой, но я конкретно встрял. Надо выкарабкиваться! К сути
Начал на питоне пописывать код

```
def convert_to_binary(value_to_convert):
    genes = []
    while(value_to_convert // 2 >= 1):
        genes.append(value_to_convert % 2)
        value_to_convert = value_to_convert // 2
    genes.append(1)
    return genes.reverse()

class Chromosome:
    def __init__(self):
        self.genes = []
    def set_genes(self, chromosome_val):
        self.genes = convert_to_binary(chromosome_val)


c1 = Chromosome()
c1.set_genes(6)
print(c1.genes)
```

Здесь хочу для каждого объекта переводить число из десятичной системы в двоичную и хранить биты в массиве. Использую для этого класс Chromosome и метод convert_to_binary. Метод print выдаёт None. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему такое могло произойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отличие от строк, когда вы вызываете метод reverse у списка, это метод только меняет сам список, но не создает его копию. Поэтому вам сначала сделует сделать genes.reverse(), а потом уже return genes. В итоге функция будет выглядеть так:

```
def convert_to_binary(value_to_convert):
    genes = []
    while(value_to_convert // 2 >= 1):
        genes.append(value_to_convert % 2)
        value_to_convert = value_to_convert // 2
    genes.append(1)
    genes.reverse()
    return genes
```

А если ее оптимизировать,то так:

```
def convert_to_binary(value_to_convert):
    return list(map(int, str(bin(value_to_convert))[2:]))
```